Does ArcticDB support MongoDB connection with credentials?
I utilize Arctic for saving timeseries data and I provide MongoDB connection to Arctic ( so Mongo serves as the database essentially ). After some time, I wanted to implement credentials to strengthen the security of the connection so I did add basic username and password to MongoDB needed for connection.
When I instantiate the Arctic with normal connection without any credentials in the string:
store = Arctic('mongodb://localhost:27017')

I get no error essentially. I then implemented basic username and credentials into MongoDB, so I updated the string accordingly:
store = Arctic('mongodb://admin:admin@localhost:27017')

And I get very specific error internally of Arctic:
TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable

I then tried using MongoClient from pymongo without utilizing credentials in the connection string nor connection string directly but that failed with the same error.

It would really surprise me if authentication is not supported by Arctic. Perhaps this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Hi Greetings from ArcticDB team. We don't support officially support mongodb yet but connecting to any mongodb should not be a problem, as the connection string is just simply being passed to the underlying mongo SDK.
ArcticDB should throw an exception if it does run into a problem. It will be great if you can share it.
Please consider joining our community and raise the issue here
Your question will be answered more promptly there!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
